# Cells not being colored after row 96 on output excel sheet

Tags: excel, apache

I am using Apache POI to output my program's logging to an excel sheet. Some cells need to be colored, so I am setting and changing styles to choose the color I want.

```
HSSFCellStyle style5 = (HSSFCellStyle) wb.createCellStyle();
        style5.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.BRIGHT_GREEN.index);
        style5.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        cell.setCellStyle(style5);
```

I included the above code inside my

```
setBackgroundColor(Rows aRow, Cell cell){}
```

function. "Rows" is a custom class I created, and "cell" is the cell I pass to it so it knows which cell I am refering to. This is all the code related to adding color to a cell. I have a flag that prints out to the console every time this function is called, to keep track of how many times it goes into this part of the code and to compare it to how many times it SHOULD go into this part of the code. The console printouts indicate everything is working fine and the color should have been added to the cells.

However, every time I run my program, no cells are colored past row #96 of the excel sheet. I have no idea why this is happening. If the output excel sheet is under 96 rows,  then everything is colored fine as it should be. But if the file is bigger, (bigger than 96 rows) it will stop coloring after row 96.

I would really appreciate your help.